# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on mac 10.5

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

My problem started the other day when I tried to run a jar file that was compiled in java 1.6 from a friend. I then got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

Since I was only using java 1.5 obviously. So I updated using the system update. This did not help and when I ran:

```
java -version
```

in the terminal it still said I had java 1.5. I then saw on the internet that there was an "java SE update 4" on apples download page available. I downloaded and installed this file but it still wouldn't work. I gave up and decided to go back to my programming in eclipse. When I tried to compile and run my application in eclipse I now recieved the same error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and it wouldnt let me proceed. I tried right clicking the project and viewing the properties but it wouldnt let me, just gave me another error. I figured I might messed something up when I installed the new java version so I tried reinstalling eclipse but it still gave me the same error. I tried creating a new workspace but that wouldnt help either. I then figured I would try to compile throught the terminal using:

```
javac main.java
java main
```

But I still get the same error. I went in under systems settings and diabled "java 1.6" and i tried creating new projects with both javaSE-5 and javaSE-6 but it just wont work. My thoughts now is if it has something to do with eclipse not being able to access the bin & src directories in the project directory but that should work if i reinstalled it? I also saw someone mention setting the classpath in os x but I don't know. I would really need some help solving this issue since a lot of my work rely on eclipse working. I would rather not have to reinstall the whole OS just because of this but if I can't get it to work I guess there is no other alternative.

Best Regards
Jonas Kristensson

Comment: Could you tell us which class def is not found?

Answer (score 3):

"Reinstall the whole OS"?  Good lord, no.

Your problems have nothing to do with the version of Java.  You don't understand how CLASSPATH works.

The class you were trying to run wasn't on the CLASSPATH.  If your friend gave you a JAR, you need to add it to your CLASSPATH and use the fully-resolved class name to run it.

A word of advice for your future mental health: When you have problems, don't assume the worst and jump to extreme measures.  Try the simple solutions first.

Comment: Set the CLASSPATH in Eclipse.  You don't have an Eclipse problem.   How do you add to CLASSPATH in the IDE?  That's the lesson you need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to run a jar file that was compiled in java 1.6 from a friend. ... Since I was only using java 1.5 obviously

Note that if this was really the case you'd get a `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`, since Java 5 can't run classes compiled for Java 6 (it might be able to do so, but the class files say "I'm Java 6+" (class version 50) and thus Java 5 would just refuse to run it (max class version in Java 5 would be 49).

Comment: Hi Thomas yes you are probably correct. I probably got java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. when I ran that file so I guess I have to assume that the error occured when I updated my java but I just can't understand why everything got screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with

```
javac -source 1.5 target 1.5 .....
```